# Cannot install google plugin for eclipse 3.7

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I used this link http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7
When installing, an error message appeared, is said that

---

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.highlighter,2.9.1.v20100421-0704
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.memory,2.9.1.v20100421-0704
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.misc,2.9.1.v20100421-0704
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.queries,2.9.1.v20100421-0704
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.snowball,2.9.1.v20100421-0704
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.spellchecker,2.9.1.v20100421-0704
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.200.v201103170302
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.server.core,1.2.202.v20110419
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.core,1.1.500.v201104191926
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.ui,1.0.600.v201103022054
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.core,1.1.500.v201104191551
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core,1.1.100.v201104272153
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.manipulation,1.0.300.v201104272153
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui,1.1.100.v201105041953

---

and canceled my installation. 
I'm using mac os 10.7, eclipse 3.7 for java developer
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Just uncheck 'Contact al update sites during install ....'

Comment: It worked for me although I installed from a local file (I downloaded the ADT manually).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq?hl=sv-SE#wstinstallerror

You need to have the wst update site added to your available sources. For 3.6, that'd be the following steps:

Select Help > Install New Software...
Click the link for Available Software Sites.
Ensure there is an update site named Helios. If this is not present, click Add... and enter http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios for the Location.

It looks like 3.7 is called Indigo, so try adding http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

Answer (score 1):

I removed and re-added the update site (http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7) to Eclipse, then ran my updates again and everything worked??? Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I had installed eclipse in the Application folder. I moved it out of it and restarted eclipse (note: drag drop does not work, it creates an alias, copy-paste the eclipse folder and then delete the one under Application).Now it seems to find all dependencies and dependent plugins. Seems like the problem was because "Application" folder has some auth issues.